# In Syme vs. UnSweet's second USTO 2016 Tak game, at what point should Syme have defended against a C-file threat?

Tags: tak

In [Syme vs. UnSweet's second USTO 2016 game](https://youtu.be/e_JqK7shQ8Y?t=1h3m28s) (the commentator gets a few things wrong, worth noting), UnSweet won by tinuë on a C-file threat. This threat started to emerge very early in the game, and was identifiable even with the early Cc4 capstone move.

Obviously, at some point, Syme lost the white advantage by permitting falling into tak off the C-file threat. The question I'm wondering is, at what point should Syme have started to work against UnSweet's growing board advantage?

There are a few specific moves I'm wondering about:

1. On moves 6-7, the a2/b6 and c4/c6 response really seems like it lost Syme a lot of tempo. a2 does pin UnSweet's capstone, but also, UnSweet's capstone is in a great position for forming a tak threat anyway, so pinning it doesn't seem to do a whole lot. Then, trying to cut the C-file road with c4 seems like it leaves the flat stranded, where there are equally blocking moves that would persist in building a tak threat. Am I misreading these moves, or were these actual mistakes?
2. On the next move, where Syme plays d6 and UnSweet plays b4, would Syme b4 have been a better move? It would guarantee the the flats at c4, and partially guarantee b3, while rebuilding a tak threat - which seems to be exactly the threat that UnSweet then exploits. The other concern is that d6 can't adequately threaten c6, and therefore can't threaten a C-file tak threat. But leaving the 6-rank road to grow also seems like a poor idea, especially when d6 totally fortifies c6. So my secondary question is: would c5 have been a better move than d6?
3. Instead of placing on move 10, though, Syme then responds to this situation with b3+, which both breaks up their road and loses them a bit of tempo. Is this move an error? It starts towards rebuilding a road, but it doesn't seem to do it in a way that can't be easily counteracted by UnSweet, and really doesn't pose that much of a threat.

It seems like this section of moves (6-10) really messed Syme up. Is this roughly the region that I should be looking at when I dissect this game?